# replacing each string of one or more spaces and/or tabs by a single space

Tags: c

So this is my code so far, I am trying to replaces multiple spaces and tabs into single space. The input is multiple lines with multiple tabs and spaces (including mix tab and spaces sentence). I am stuck after writing this much:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NONBLANK 'a'
main(){
int c, lastc;

lastc = NONBLANK;

while (( c = getchar()) !=EOF) {
    if (c != ' ' || lastc !=' '){
        if (c != '\t' || lastc !='\t'){

                putchar(c);
            lastc = c;}

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your idea to save the last char is good, but you should revise your logic. Space or tab? Print a space when the last character wasn't a space or tab. Anything else? Print it regardless of the last char.

Comment: At a glance (unless I'm missing a bug) this seems like it should replace a run of spaces with a single space, and a run of tabs with a single tab. Is this what you intend, or should a mix of spaces and tabs also be replaced by one character? You may also be interested in the `isspace` function, although it also catches newlines. http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/isspace.3.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `getchar()` echoes the input as it is typed, confusing you by echoing the spaces and tabs you wanted to condense. Try this using the non-echoing `getch()`. I haven't used `EOF` to end, but *return*, experiment with this as you will.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, lastc = -1;
    while ((c = getch()) != '\r') {
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\t'){
            if (lastc == ' ' || lastc == '\t')
                putchar(' ');
            putchar(c);
            }   
        lastc = c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please also note your incorrect declaration of `main()`.